# Getting Omni complete to work on vim 7.2 on windows

Tags: python, vim

I am trying to use the Omni complete feature with gVim 7.2 but on windows I keep getting an error that says

Error: require vim compiled with +python
E117: unknown function: pythoncomplete#complete

seems like it might be because gvim 7.2 is compiled with 2.4 and I have 2.5 installed. I have downloaded the 2.5 compiled binaries from [here](http://www.gooli.org/blog/gvim-72-with-python-2526-support-windows-binaries/) , but still no joy.

The python I have on my machine was installed as part of Cygwin (I have python.exe and python2.5.exe in c:\cygwin\bin) . I tried copying these two files to a directory C:\python25 in case that was the path that was specified during recompilation.

Is there anyway to get omni complete to work without having to recompile gvim myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cygwin Python won't work. Just install the Windows Python from http://python.org.

I had the same problem, but with a plugin - pyflakes. I solved it by installing Python 2.6 FOR ALL USERS, and using a gvim.exe binary downloaded from here:

http://www.gooli.org/blog/gvim-72-with-python-2526-support-windows-binaries/

Comment: Cool. That worked. Had to install the 32 bit version of Python though even though I am using Win 7 64 bit, because the recompiled gVim binaries above I understand are 32 bit