# why i failed to use omni auto complete when i edit source code?

Tags: autocomplete, vim, vim-plugin, omnicomplete

vim a.py

input:

```
impo
```

then press:  **Cx Co**

omin autocomplete just failed with the following message, why?

```
Error: Required vim compiled with +python                                                                                                                      E117: Unknown function: pythoncomplete#Complete
Press ENTER or type command to continue


vim --version | grep python
-python +quickfix +reltime -rightleft -ruby +scrollbind -signs +smartindent
```

this issue is not the same as [Getting Omni complete to work on vim 7.2 on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897022/getting-omni-complete-to-work-on-vim-7-2-on-windows), since i use vim on linux, not windows.

**Edit 1:**

i can use omni autocomplete on another host now, **but i canont autocomplete for urlopen, why?**

```
from urllib import url
```

press CxCo, then the error message appears:

```
-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

**Edit 2**

don't know why omni not works again, confusing...

Answer (score 2):

vim was compiled without python support.  You can tell because `vim --version` outputs `-python` instead of `+python`.

Comment: That would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is spelled out for you: Vim is not compiled with Python support, and the solution is to install a proper build.

Supposing you are on Ubuntu or another Debian derivative, you probably only need to do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

If you are working on a headless server via SSH, replace `vim-gnome` by `vim-nox`.